# Solving system of equations in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, infinite-loop

I am unable to solve this system of equations in Mathematica. Where the third equation takes value (on the right hand side) from `0.00001` to `0.001` in an interval of `0.00001`. I have generated list of values for the third equation which has been named by `b[[n]]`, where `n=999`. Now I want to solve these equations which will result in `n` number of sets of solutions `(x, y, z)`. I have tried with the code

```
Solve[{-16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x + 2 y)^2 == 0.00007,-16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x - y + 2 z)^2 == 0.0024, 4 a^2 (x - y)== b[[n]]},{x,y,z}]
```

which is not yielding any result (here `a=0.5`). Is it possible to solve this kind of system of equations at a time. Any kind of suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try the code `b = {0.0001, 
  0.001}; Solve[{-16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x + 2 y)^2 == 
    0.00007, -16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x - y + 2 z)^2 == 0.0024,
   4 a^2 (x - y) == b[[-1]]} /. a -> 0.5, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: Have you assigned a value to the index `n`?

Answer (score 2):

To visualize the solution

```
assume = {Element[{a, b}, Reals]};

eqns = {
    -16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x + 2 y)^2 == 7/100000,
    -16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x - y + 2 z)^2 == 3/1250,
    4 a^2 (x - y) == b, assume} // Flatten;

Clear[sol]

sol[a_, b_] = {x, y, z} /.
    Solve[eqns, {x, y, z}, Reals] //

   Simplify[#, assume] &;

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[sol[a, b]],
  Evaluate[{b, Sequence @@ br}],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{a, .5}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{br, {-1, 1}, "b range"},
  {{0.00001, 0.001}, {-1, 1}},
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 `Evaluate[{b, Sequence @@ br}]` is a really nice way to set different ranges for the parameter `b`.

Answer (score 1):

If you give `Solve` some information about the parameters `a` and `b` it will yield a general solution. When one writes `a>0`, `Solve` understands this to mean that `a` is a real number greater than zero.

```
sol = Solve[{-16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x + 2 y)^2 == 
    7/100000, -16 a^4 (x - y)^2 + 16 a^4 (x - y + 2 z)^2 == 24/10000, 
   4 a^2 (x - y) == b, a > 0, b > 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

The solution is a bit long to paste so I show the solution for `x`, `y` and `z`.

`x` is given by `sol[[1, 1, 2, 1]]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`y` is given by `sol[[1, 2, 2, 1]]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`z` has two solutions given by `sol[[1, 3, 2, 1]]` and `sol[[2, 3, 2, 1]]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]